# What is the least crazy/degenerate example of a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that it is possible to construct extremely weird subsets of $\mathbb R$, or of $\mathbb R^3$, that are non-Lebesgue-measurable. For example, the ones used in the Banach-Tarski paradox.

Are there "less crazy" examples of non Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$?

I am asking in order to get a feeling of how degenerate a set has to be before I have to start worrying about Lebesgue-measurability problems.

Comment: You may want to ask for the extent of the definable Lebesgue measurable sets, where definability is in the classical descriptive set-theoretic sense: All Borel sets are measurable, as are all their images under continuous functions (and their complements). These sets go well beyond any sets you find in classical analysis. Beyond these sets you run into set-theoretic issues related to large cardinals, consistency and independence.

Comment: On the other hand, there are several standard examples of nonmeasurable sets: Any well-ordering of a non-null set of reals, any Vitali set, any Luzin set, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest example I know of is a Vitali set (partition $[0,1]$ into equivalence classes of the relation $\sim$, where $x \sim y$ iff $x - y$ is rational, and then pick exactly one member of each equivalence class).

This construction is sort of "characteristic" of non-measurable sets, in my experience - a set that isn't Lebesgue-measurable can't be Borel (or $\mathbf{\Sigma^1_1}$ or $\mathbf{\Pi^1_1}$, which are basically the next level up) which means that they can't have "nice" topological definitions. Another way of thinking about it is that the standard proof that not all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are Lebesgue-measurable relies on the Axiom of Choice, so you can expect any examples to be "choicey".

My rule of thumb is that if a set has a natural topological definition, it's probably measurable. If its definition involves "choosing" something infinitely many times, then it's probably not measurable.

Comment: It's not just that the *standard* proof that not all subset of $\mathbb R$ uses the Axiom of Choice - every proof must because it is consistent, without AC, that every subset of $\mathbb R$ is measurable.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Well, no - if *every* proof required Choice, then that would mean the statement "there exists a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not Lebesgue-measurable" would be equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. But there are models of ZFC in which Choice fails but not all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable. I mean, these models wind up having something that *looks* a lot like Choice (e.g., Choice restricted to choosing reals) but they don't need full-blown Choice.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly as you want, but non-measurable sets must be “crazy,” because all Borel sets are measurable (in fact, measurable sets are equal to Borel sets up to a set of measure zero).

Answer (score 3):

Solovay showed that is consistent with ZF set theory (without the full Axiom of Choice but with Dependent Choice and an inaccessible cardinal) that all sets of reals are measurable.  Thus any example of a nonmeasurable set must be "crazy".

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. We know that not all sets are Lebesque measurable, so how is the result that "all sets of reals are measurable" is consistent with ZF, relevant for the result that a nonmeasurable set must be crazy?

Comment: For any provably nonmeasurable set, the construction and/or proof must involve the Axiom of Choice (or something else outside pure ZF).  In particular you're not going to get something "explicit".